# join multiple tables with where and Where IN

Tags: mysql

**The challenge**

I'm trying to join user table to the list of brands they follow (through followers) and fetch the entire list of products. I also want to right join the Orders table where product is available and the Stage field (in Orders) is set to 'basket'.

**Tables**

User : ID, Name

```
+-------+-------------+
| ID    | Name        |
+-------+-------------+
| 1     |   User 1    |
| 2     |   User 2    |
+-------+-------------+
```

Brand : ID, Name

```
+-------+-------------+
| ID    | Name        |
+-------+-------------+
| 1     |   brand 1   |
| 2     |   brand 2   |
+-------+-------------+
```

Products : ID, NAME, Brand ID, Price

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| ID    | Name      | Brand       | Price       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1     | product 1 | 1           | 5           |
| 2     | product 2 | 1           | 6           |
| 3     | product 3 | 2           | 7           |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Orders: ID, User ID, Product ID, Stage (basket)

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| ID    | User      | Product     | Stage       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1     | 1         | 1           | basket      |
| 2     | 1         | 2           | basket      |
| 3     | 1         | 1           | completed   |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Followers : User, Brand IDs

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| ID    | User      | Brand       |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 1     | 1         |   1         |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Orders.ID
from Orders
inner join User on  Followers.User = User.ID
inner join Brand on Followers.Brand =  Brand.ID
inner join Product on Product.Brand = Brand.ID
right join order on (Orders.Product = Product.ID and Orders.User = User.ID)
where Orders.Stage IN ("basket")
```